# What is the minimum width of this div

Tags: html, css

Ok. I am trying to find what the minimum width of `row1` should be. At the moment it is 791px, but I don't understands the maths behind it.

- There are 2 x 10px padding left and right. = 20px
- Each box is 75px wide. There are 10 boxes. = 750px
- Each box has a 1px border on the right and left = 20px (10 boxes * 2px)
- All boxes also have 2px margin on the right except for last child = 18px (9*2px)

That gives me a total of 808px. Thats ought to be the minimum width of `row1`.

**HTML**

```
<div class ="board">
    <div class ="row1">
                                <div class="box"></div>
                                <div class="box"></div>
                                <div class="box"></div>
                                <div class="box"></div>
                                <div class="box"></div>
                                <div class="box"></div>
                                <div class="box"></div>
                                <div class="box"></div>
                                <div class="box"></div>
                                <div class="box"></div>
    </div>

 </div>
```

**CSS**
/* Board Structure */

```
.board{
    background: #EBEBE0;
    height: 200px;  
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 835px;
}
.row1{
    background: #FFDCDC;
    height: 52px;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 791px;
}
/* Position Boxes*/
.box{
    width: 75px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2px;
}
div.box:last-child {
margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Could it be that you're including margins, padding and borders in your calculations without setting `box-sizing:border-box;`?

Comment: Change from float: left; to display: inline-block; floats take your item out of the dom.

Comment: @Graham I don't understand what you mean? the boxes have 1px border, so that makes their width 75px + 2px (left and right border).

Comment: Do you really have that white space in between class and = in your code , or is it just a bad copy/paste, else , classes .board & .row1 won't be applied.

Comment: @GCyrillus There is space yes in my actual code.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? The minimum width is whatever you set it to. Without changing your CSS the row renders to be 811px wide.

Comment: Agree with @Cam. The float changes the dimensions, if you use inline-block it adds up but the width that worked for me was 825px:
http://jsfiddle.net/chace/L2JRJ/11/

Comment: Graham I want to set the width of that div to the minimum required, meaning I want to put all my 10 boxes inside that div without them overflowing.

Comment: @chonerman your boxes still overflow row1

Comment: @GrahamWalters I know it is correct because I was doing trial and error with the width until it fixed exactly. I asked this question because I want to know the maths behind it all.

Comment: @EltonFrederik for .row1 the minimum I was able to fit without overflow was 824px, for the .board it remains the 835px from your original post. I also changed what Cam suggested by removing the float and adding display: inline-block to the .box -- Latest fiddle works without overflow on IE9 and FF : http://jsfiddle.net/chace/L2JRJ/14/

Comment: @chonerman your 824px still overflows on my screen, im using Chrome.

Comment: @EltonFrederik it seems in Chrome the "overflow: auto;" causes the scrollbar to put the last box on the next line. By removing it the fiddle works in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/chace/L2JRJ/23/

Comment: @chonerman 824px doesn't make sense mathamatically. One thing I have noticed is when I get rid of the borders around the boxes, the maths works as I expect it. Upon further inspection I find that in Chrome the width of the boxes varies from 75px-77px when I do use the borders. I think therein lies the problem.

Answer (score 1):

75 * 10 = 750 - ten boxes
10 * 2 = 20 - padding on row
9 * 2 = 18 - margin on each box except last

That adds up to 788, which is probably the number you are looking for. This [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MV8LY/) shows the boxes are centered inside the row with equal space on the left and right.

Note, the contents of a div do not drive its size when you explicitly set it in the css:

```
.row1{
    background: #FFDCDC;
    height: 52px;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 790px; /* explicit div width*/
}
```

If you put elements who's sum will add up to more than 791px, then it will create a scroll bar for the overflow. This is also based on your CSS. But, because the boxes are set to float, they will not contribute to the overflow sum.

Comment: @MikeKoch Yes. Good catch. Updated.

Comment: Also there is no margin on last child. And 790px is not wide enough, the boxes overflow.

Comment: So far, 790px and float: left works, 790px and inline-block overflows, 791px and inline-block overflows too.

Comment: I think :last-child would be appropriate here

Comment: @Bic, should we count the 1px borders around the boxes? Can you edit your answer to remove the padding, since you correctly pointed out we shouldn't count the padding as part of the width.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum width for `row1` is `788px`.

```
75px * 10 = 750px // width
2px  * 10 = 20px  // border
2px  * 9  = 18px  // margin
788px             // total
```

If you want the containing width, it would be `788px + 20px`

Comment: That is what I expected too. But it still overflows.

Comment: @EltonFrederik sorry about the comments above, I forgot to remove your width when I was checking the rendered output.

Comment: Also what about the 1px border I have around each box? Doesn't that essentially make the boxes 77px wide?

Comment: @EltonFrederik it's overflowing because you set the width on `.board`, try 100%

Comment: @EltonFrederik padding goes on the inside of an element. It does not actually increase the size of the element, but rather decreases the size of the insides; less content will fit.

Comment: the width `.board` is not relevant here I think, because `.board` is wide enough to contain `.row1` that is all that matters about the width of `.board` is it not?

Comment: @EltonFrederik I'm not seeing any overflow? [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6c52y/) And I mixed up padding and borders, your boxes have borders not padding so yes the size goes to 77px per box plus 18px in margin

Comment: @GrahamWalters your fiddle is correct, but in my browser it overflows, also can you explain why you got rid of the width on `.board`?

Comment: @Bic Padding goes on the outside of the element and **does** increase the size of an element. You can include it using `box-sizing:border-box;` but his CSS does not include `box-sizing:border-box;`

Comment: @EltonFrederik what exactly is overflowing? 808px is **never** going to fit on a 600px wide screen without overflowing, so can you please explain what is overflowing?

Comment: @GrahamWalters Your 788px `row1` overflows. the 10 boxes with their margins, borders, paddings and what not, don't fit into 788px. In the fiddle they do, but not in my Chrome broswer which is strange. 791px is the only time it doesnt overflow in  my browser.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46289/discussion-between-elton-frederik-and-graham-walters)